# Check If a List of Substrings Is Within Pandas DF Column AND Replace DF Value With Substring If True

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am using python 3.8 in a Jupyter Notebook

What is the best way to see if a string in our dataframe column contains a substring within a list and then REPLACE our dataframe column value with the substring it contained? Note: there will only be one match. Mutliple substrings will not match on our comparison.

Ex: '/google123' contains a substring 'google', so the new value in our df would be 'google' instead of '/google123'.

**Dummy Data Below:**

```
import pandas as pd

channel = ['google','bing','facebook','google','facebook']
page = ['/cars?exp=123', '/google123', '/toytrucks', '/cars','/randompage']

compare_list = ['google','cars?exp']

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(channel,page), columns=['channel','page'])
```

**My Attempt Was:**

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
        
    cur_page = df.loc[i, "page"]
        
    for x in compare_list:
     
        if x in cur_page:
            cur_page = x
            
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apply to pass the values to the function:

```
def check(x):
    for i in compare_list:
        if i in x:
            return i
    return x

df['page'] = df['page'].apply(check)
```

Outputs:

|  | channel | page |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | google | cars?exp |
| 1 | bing | google |
| 2 | facebook | /toytrucks |
| 3 | google | /cars |
| 4 | facebook | /randompage |

PS. in case you just wish to extract the words, you can also use regex:

```
df['page'].str.extract('([^\W\d_]+)')
```

Comment: Does our compare list need to be defined in the function, as a global variable, or can it be fed into the function like passing "x" in?

Comment: If you don't modify the list inside the function, it won't need to be provided in any way. It will use the one in the main namespace by default with no name error.

Comment: Could the same function be used to FILTER my dataframe? Filtering down to only records who either matched or did not match? Wasn't sure if the above could serve a dual purpose.

Comment: @CarsonWhitley you could replace `return x` with `return None` and then drop the empty rows: `df.dropna(subset=['page'])`